# How to change plot value color in highcharts?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I want to change the color of plot numeric values(1000, 2000...9000) as shown in below snapshot. I couldn't find an option to do so in highcharts api.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst your comments are't that clear I believe you want the xAsis lines color changed:

```
 xAxis: {
             lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
        }
```

Add the above to the `highcharts` object: `graph.highcharts({});`

See here for more details: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

**Edit**

In that case you'll still want the `xAsis`. Thankfully highCharts let us do things as simply as `CSS`:

```
   xAxis: {
            labels:  {
                style: {
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            }
```